# Is there a time delay before thin film interference begins?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, interference

I was thinking about an experiment mentioned by Feynman in his book QED.  He was describing the partial reflection and partial transmission of light at an air/glass boundary and explaining that for certain conditions you might see 8% of the light reflected but that this is just an average.  Depending on the thickness of the glass you will observer between 0% and 16% reflection.  He then mentions that this cycling between maximum and minimum reflection has been observed to occur or 100 000 000 cycles corresponding to a thickness of glass of 50 metres.

If we use a classical electromagnetic wave model of light (which is not what Feynman is doing) wouldn't we expect a delay between when the light begins to reflect and when the effects of thin film interference begin because of the slight delay for the EM wave to reach the far surface of the glass and come back to begin interference.  So we might observe 8% reflection and then $\frac{100}{c}$ seconds later it might change to some other value depending on the thickness.

**Has this been observed?**  I would assume not because it seems to contradict the photon model, most obviously in the case of light so dim it hits the glass with a interval of over $\frac{100}{c}$ between each photon.

Comment: Why do you think the electromagnetic waves in this model are not classical? I suppose this interference was calculated using monochromatic plane waves, which directly origin from Maxwell's equations without any quantum effect.
If you add a "switch-on moment" to the plane wave, it isn't monochromatic anymore. That would indeed make some time for the interference to build up necessary.
The last paragraph is very confusing to me. Why should dim light contradict the photon model? In all experiments where single photons are detected one uses dim light.